# Why don't things balance after they stop spinning?

Tags: angular-momentum, friction

When I spin a penny, I spin it on its "edge" (circumference). So why is it that when the penny inevitably stops spinning, it never comes to rest on its edge, instead falling onto one of its faces? It is not a problem with the "thinness" of the penny; its possible to balance a penny on its edge in a couple of seconds.

Comment: How are you spinning the penny? Fingers most probably won't be able to give it a fully horizontal impulse, equal in both points in two exactly opposite sides of the coin.

Comment: @SJuan76 I am spinning it with my fingers! please elaborate on why a not-fully-horizontal impulse, etc. would ultimately cause the coin to fall.

Comment: The easiest way to see is the point of application of the force. If you apply it not in the center, but higher or lower, the penny will become unstable and fail (test it with a static penny). If the spin force is not simmetric, the penny would move over the table and a resistence force will appear in the contact point.

Answer (score 3):

The penny is usually not balanced when you spin it - it is precessing like a gyroscope. That means that as long as it has significant angular momentum, the torque due to gravity will not be able to topple it. As friction slows the penny down, the gyroscope effect becomes weaker until it drops.

If the penny were spinning on a low friction surface about a perfectly vertical axis it would remain upright. Would be a fun experiment to try.

Comment: "*the torque due to gravity will not be able to topple it*" is physical nonsense: the torque due to gravity leads to precession and nutation, but doesn't topple the penny.